# send email for single email ID without using Intent in android

Tags: android, email, smtp, gmail

I am developing an application that has a form to send email without in-built application. I have seen so many examples for email sending. In all the examples, it is for so many email ID. That means we can send email to multiple persons at a time. But I want to send email to one person only. I am following this tutorial. Please let me know where and what should I have to change the code.

http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/

From this tutorial in the **ToEmail** box, we can add multiple email ID. But I want to add a single email ID only.Please help me where should I change this.This is the code I have edited from this tutorial..plzzz help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Contact extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener
{

    Button submit1,clear;
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    Spinner spin;

    String[] selction = { "I want to request a mobile feature", 
            "I want to tell about something that I like",
            "I want to tell you about something that I do not like",
            "I have general comments", 
            "I want to contact the office",
            "I want to suggest an improvement in the church premise"};  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,selction);  
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  


        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
        spin.setAdapter(aa);  


//--------------------Submit_Button_Start-----------------------------------------------------------        

        final Button submit1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.i("SendMailActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");
                String fromEmail ="user@gmail.com";
                String fromPassword="password";
                String toEmails="anything@gmail.com";
                //List<String> toEmailList = Arrays.asList(toEmails.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                //Log.i("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);

                String emailBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
                new SendMailTask(Contact.this).execute(fromEmail,fromPassword, toEmails, emailBody);
            }
        });

//--------------------Submit_Button_End-----------------------------------------------------------      


        clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        /*ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.question,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    }

    public boolean onCactivity_list_itemreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact, menu);
        return true;
    }
/*
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v1)
    {

        if(v1==clear)
        {
            et1.setText("");
            et2.setText("");
            et3.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        /*
        new AlertDialog.Builder(Contact1.this)
    .setMessage("Your requested has been Accepted\nThank You")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
      dialog.cancel();
        }
    })  
        .show();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should just build a list with only one item. Something like:

```
...
List<String> toEmailList = new ArrayList<String>();
toEmailList.add("anything@gmail.com");
...
```